# angularJS advanced search filter using JSON file

Tags: angularjs

I have a drop down contains, **customer number and PANno**, based on the selection i need to filter the details.

```
customers.json:
---------------
    {  
       "txns":[  
          {                   
             "CustomerNumber":140000000034,                 
             "PANNo":"AOOPT7897C"
          },
          {  
             "CustomerNumber":150000000027,                 
             "PANNo":"AOOPT7897C"
          }
     ]
    }
```

### controller

```
$scope.customerSearch = function(){         
    $scope.searchStr = $scope.customerSearchStr;                    
            var params = {
                'key': 'CustomerNumber',
                'searchStr': $scope.customerSearchStr
            }                       
            CustomerSearchService.list(params, function(response) {      
                $scope.customers = response.customers;    
            });
        }
```

### service

```
.factory('CustomerSearchService', ['$resource', function ($resource) { 
  return $resource('../app/data/customers.json', {}, {
      'list': { method: 'GET', isArray: false}
  });
}]);
```

**Is it possible to search it in local json file?**

[image]

Comment: What do you mean for 'local json file'? Do you mean a file saved on your machine o a json loaded in a variable as a string?

Comment: it is stored in a local folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see the JSON as a Javascript Object (the "JSO" in "JSON"), so the same way you search any array you can search the JSON.

Example using the $filter provider:

```
$filter('filter')(yourObjectName.txns, { 'CustomerNumber': searchParameter.CustomerNumber})[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used this library called [Sifter](https://github.com/brianreavis/sifter.js/) in the past and really liked it.